# Tensorflow 0.12.0rc tf.summary.scalar() error using placeholders

Tags: tensorflow

Prior to tf 0.12.0rc I've used summary placeholders of the form:

```
tag_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
val_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float)
sum_op = tf.scalar_summary(tag_ph, val_ph)
...
feed_dict = {tag_ph:[some string], val_ph:[some val]}
sum_str = sess.run(sum_op, feed_dict)
writer.add_summary(sum_str)
```

After upgrading to 0.12.0 and changing `tf.scalar_summary()` to `tf.summary.scalar()` the use of a placeholder for the `name` parameter gives the following error:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

There is no error if I use a static string for `name`, but I'd like to change the string as the evaluation progresses. How can I do that?

Minimal example:

```
tag = 'test'
val = 1.234
tag_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.string, [])
val_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [])
scalar_op = tf.summary.scalar(tag_ph, val_ph)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('/tmp/summary_placeholders', sess.graph)
feed_dict = {tag_ph:tag, val_ph:val}
sum_str = sess.run(scalar_op, feed_dict)
writer.add_summary(sum_str)
writer.flush()
```

This same code (after reverting tf.summary names) works in TF 0.11.0

Comment: can you post some code that reproduces the error?

Comment: I added a minimum example at the bottom of the op and also changed from tf.summary.image to tf.summary.scalar for simplicity. Both show the same issue.

Comment: So it seems the API has changed to work on Python value instead of TensorFlow Tensor. Maybe @danmane has an idea of work-around....but this seems like an unusual usage of add_summary

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Thanks, but is there a preferred method of writing evaluation metrics to tensorboard during training if they are developed outside of tensorflow?

Comment: tracking feature request for supporting tag names as tensors: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6603

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is how to write non-Tensorflow data as summaries in version >=0.12, here's an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('custom_summaries')
summary = tf.Summary()
mydata = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
for name, data in mydata.items():
    summary.value.add(tag=name, simple_value=data)
    summary_writer.add_summary(summary, global_step=1)

summary_writer.flush()
```

TensorBoard merges summaries from all files in logdir and displays them, ie, if you do `tensorboard --logdir=.` you'll see something like this

[image]